# How should I use argcomplete in zsh?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, zsh, tab-completion

I'm using [`argcomplete`](https://github.com/kislyuk/argcomplete) to have <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion in Bash.

`argcomplete` offers global completion for `bash`, but doesn't for `zsh`.

I would like to create a file `~/.zsh_completion`, to contain the to be completed files. This file should generate autocompletion for those files when it's sourced from `~/.zshrc`.

How do I do that?

Comment: `man zshcompsys` or [Completion System online doc](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html). Zsh has a much more sophisticated completion system, and that's one reason why Zsh is loved by millions. It's usually advised to start with some configuration framework like [`Prezto`](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto), so that you get collective wisdom out of the box. And I don't know what you mean by "I would like to create a file ... to contain the to be completed files." Zsh completion is command based, and it can complete to different things for different commands.

Comment: And if you want to complete just to a predefined list, that's of course possible (Zsh is Turing complete) and pretty easy, but I won't say that's advised.

Comment: The question isn't about generic path-completion, it's about adding completion for arguments of python scripts.  That's what the `argcomplete` lib is about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Argcomplete author here. I just released argcomplete v3, which supports zsh natively, without the `bashcompinit` compatibility layer, and with full official support for completion descriptions and global completion (which gets installed by `activate-global-python-argcomplete` into `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` by default, but that behavior is configurable). Please give it a try.

Comment: That's nice to hear!

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working on MacOS 14 (Sonoma).  I've followed the instructions and `activate-global-python-argcomplete` runs, installing to `/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/python-argcomplete` and `/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_python-argcomplete`  but even after a reboot there is no completing going on.

Answer (score 6):

Alright there is a way to do it, but it's not the way I really wanted it to be.

Anyway, here goes:

1. Install `argcomplete`:

   ```
   $ pip install argcomplete
   ```
2. Activate `argcompolete`:

   ```
   $ activate-global-python-argcomplete --user
   ```
3. Add this to `~/.zshrc`:

   ```
   autoload bashcompinit
   bashcompinit
   source ~/.bash_completion.d/python-argcomplete.sh

   eval "$(register-python-argcomplete /path/to/the/to/be/completed/file1)"
   eval "$(register-python-argcomplete /path/to/the/to/be/completed/file2)"
   eval "$(register-python-argcomplete /path/to/the/to/be/completed/file3)"
   ```

   There's probably a solution to read out the to be completed files from another file, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The docs say that global autocomplete is not supported for zsh which is too bad.

Comment: As far as I can see are step 2 and `source ~/.bash_completion.d/python-argcomplete.sh` unnecessary, they are just doing dynamically (which doesn't seem to work under zsh) what `"$(register-python-argcomplete /path/to/the/to/be/completed/file1)"` does explicitly.

Comment: It's strange, when I run the `eval "$(register-python-argcomplete /path/to/the/to/be/completed/file1)"` command manually in a already spawned zsh, I get the desired autocompletion. But adding the line to `.zshrc` does not give the autocompletion.

Comment: @tbrlpld Had the same issue. Looks like running `eval` from within the script's root path seems to work. So `cd` into the root path first.

Comment: @Lucas so you remember where you read that information? wondering if it's still the case

Answer (score 3):

I've just released a new project by the name of `pyzshcomplete` which can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyzshcomplete/). 
It is meant to provide the same functionality as `argcomplete` but for `zsh`.

Answer (score 2):

Same as Exeleration-G but in your ~/.zshrc you only put

```
eval "$(cd path/to/script; register-python-argcomplete script.name)"
```