# Can I get zsh completion from a command?

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, tab-completion

In `bash`, I can register any command to get it's completion from an arbitrary executable. E.g. in this case from a python script:

```
complete -C "/usr/bin/python2 '/home/user/bin/mycompleter.py'" mycommand
```

So the pre-existing command called `mycommand` will now get it's <kbd>TAB</kbd>-completions from the `mycompleter.py` script.

As long as `mycompleter.py` prints a completion per line and gets its input on what to complete from the `COMP_*` environemnt variables, that works fine in bash.

Is there something similar and a similar interface in `zsh`? I.e. can I write my zsh-completer in Python and register it with zsh? If yes, how? I guess, what I'm looking for is the `zsh` completion interface and whether it can be used with other languages.

I would already be pretty happy if someone could provide me with the `zsh` equivalent of the above bash line.

Comment: this might be useful: https://pypi.org/project/genzshcomp/

Comment: this is also `argcomplete` as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34797889/2667536

Comment: Thanks for the links, but that's not really what I'm looking for. What I want is to get the `zsh` completions for an **existing** command **not** written in Python from a **Python** script. Your links only seem to provide completions for commands **written** with the `argparse`, `optpars` or `getopts` modules. I might be able to extrect how these register their completions with zsh from your links, though.

Comment: my bad, sorry. Just in case, here is the zsh completion doc: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html